# Match and replace string but excluding certain combinations of match groups at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have texts that have been saved to a database without their formatting. I need to make them readable again. There are some clues to determine where paragraphs and titles used to be, but I'm stuck defining the correct pattern to wrap titles inside `<h2>` elements.

Example of a text:

> Amsterdam is trying reduce energy consumption from data centers.It's goals is to reduce consumption by 86 million kWh in the next three years.Current SituationToday all data centers combined use 460 million kWh every year

In above case, the title is `Current Situation`. I can detect the start of the title thanks to the punctuation and the end thanks to the uppercase letter of "Today" (that starts the next paragraph)

My regex works as follows:

- Matching group 1: start from punctuation
- Matching group 2: exclude more punctuation, continue until a lowercase letter ...
- Matching group 3: ...is directly followed by an uppercase letter

The Regex:

```
/([.!?])([^.!?]*?[a-z])([A-Z])/g
```

and I can surround it with `<h2>` tags by using this replace pattern:

```
"$1<h2>$2</h2>$3"
```

Unfortunately this also matches the part `.It's goals is to reduce consumption by 86 million kW` because it has the uppercase `W` (3rd matching group) glued to the lowercase `k` (second matching group)

Question: How can I exclude certain keywords like `kW` or `kWh` from matching in my second and third matching groups.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbsceLwy/1/

Comment: What are the "*certain keywords like kW or kWh*"? Please provide more clear requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to be able to easily tweak the regex to exclude valid words that have an uppercase letter in the middle, because they break the logic of the regex. "kW" or "kWh" are some examples of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using a negative Lookahead:

```
([.!?])([^.!?]*?(?!\bkWh\b)[a-z])([A-Z])
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xj6QN6/1)**.

Here, `(?!\bkWh\b)` will check the position before the last lowercase letter and ensure that it's not followed by "kWh". If you'd like to add more words, simply use the OR operator: `(?!\b(?:kWh|fOo|bAr)\b)`.

Note that `\b` checks for a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). So, it will prevent matching `kWh` , `kWh.`, `kWh:`, etc. but it will not prevent matching "kWh" when it's part of another word.

- If you wish to prevent matching "kWh" even if it's part of another word, you may remove both `\b` instances (or one of them depending on what you need).
- If, on the other hand, word boundaries are not restrictive enough for you (i.e., you only want the match to fail if "kWh" is surrounded by whitespace), then you may use:

  ```
  ([.!?])([^.!?]*?(?!kWh\s)\S[a-z])([A-Z])
  ```